# How to display '#' in Android dial pad in Titanium?

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator

In Titanium Appcelerator/Android we can open a call dial to dial a number, with this code.

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow();
win.backgroundColor = 'white';
// Create a Button.
var aButton = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title : 'Charge',
    height : 40,
    width : 150,
    top : 300,
    left : 80
});

var value = '123456789#';
win.add(aButton);
aButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    Titanium.Platform.openURL('tel:' + value);
});
win.open();
```

The question is how to display `#` in the dial pad: as of now it only shows 123456789. I tried many ways but it does not show `#`.Any other way to do that?
Ali.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a hash is just a special character, so add

```
%23
```

to your

```
  var value='123456789';
```

string.

so it will look like:-

```
  var value='123456789%23';
```

Easy.

Comment: '12%234' === encodeURIComponent('12#4') // works in Titanium, as well

Comment: i just want to dial *123*456789# but it shows number till 9 and skips # value then i tried the other way as you told by using %23 at the end of the string in this case an error comes saying NETWORK CONNECTION ERROR INVALID MMI CODE.can you please explain what could be the issue or some other solution for that? Thanks again for you help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (replace your "#" with "%23"):

```
var value = '123456789%23';
```